# onclick does not work with anchor tag in android app

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

I am trying to use an anchor tag as well call a function in javascript. I am using the following code to perform this operation.

```
<a href="'+submitUrl+'" onclick="showLoaderBefore("Loading..."); return true;" data-ajax="false" data-role="button" data-transition="slide">'+rList.name+'</a>
```

But this does not work...onclick event is not triggered...I tried putting alert in the function but it does not call that function....

Any solution for this problem?

Comment: <a href="'+submitUrl+'" onclick="showLoaderBefore('Loading...');" data-ajax="false" data-role="button" data-transition="slide">'+rList.name+'</a>

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the function is not called because of the quotes, which are not escaped:

```
onclick="showLoadedBefore("Loading...")"
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krustev/bXmCa/), which proves this.

What you can try is either use apostrophes or remove the quotes like this:

```
onclick=showLoadedBefore("Loading...")
```